# CheckedListBox get selected index

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the value of the selected index in a CheckedListBox. I tried via through an if condition and switch cases, but it is not working as expected.

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(0)==CheckState.Checked)
   {                               
      richTextBox1.Font = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
   }
}
```

Comment: Answer is in your title: `if (checkedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex) == CheckState.Checked)`

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use

```
    checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices
```

Something like

```
    foreach(int index in checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices)
    {
    if(index == 1)
    {
          //do something
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count != 0)  
{  
   // If so, loop through all checked items and print results.  
   string s = "";  
   for(int x = 0; x <= checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1 ; x++)  
   {  
      s = s + "Checked Item " + (x+1).ToString() + " = " + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x].ToString() + "\n";  
   }  
MessageBox.Show (s);  
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. Please vote if my answer is helpful for you